# MongoDB find field that is part of a longer string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know how to search for a field that contains a part of my search in MongoDB & Node, or even if it is possible ie.
Record:

{
     name: "Hello my name is robinson"
 }

Query:

{
   name: /robinson/i
}

However I don't know how to do the reverse

ie: 
Query:

{
     name: "Hello my name is robinson"
 }

Record:

{
   name: "robinson"
}

I am trying to make rules to categorise strings based on their content. Any help is much appreciated. Content may not always be broken down into words, otherwise I could have just done a split by space and searched for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Text index you should be able to find documents from a phrase text search.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms

> If the search string is a space-delimited string, $text operator performs a logical OR search on each term and returns documents that contains any of the terms.

In your example, you create an index in the "name" field of your collection:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { name: "text" } )
```

Then you can query with the $text operator:

```
db.collection.find({$text: { $search: "Hello my name is robinson"}})
```

As stated in the docs, the query returns documents that contains "Hello **or** my **or** name **or** is **or** robinson".